# Visual Studio 2013 - plugin to convert CamelCase to underscore_case in real time

Tags: visual-studio-2013, plugins

I'm looking for a plugin/extension for `Visual Studio 2013` to convert text writing as *Camel Case* into *underscore_case* **in real time** (in the moment of writing). I didn't find anything familiar.